# How to click on calendar based on day and time?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please check attached image for reference. I want to click on particular week's day and time. I tried with Xpath but always getting `NoSuchElementFoundException`.

[image]

Comment: Hi. It would be better to post a clear and concise example of your solution, with the resulting outcome, than to post a screengrab like this. Please read here about how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='rc-row rc-widget-header' and /th[contains(.,'Sun 1/22'")]]));
```

You could also try this:

```
//Create a list containing all the elements from the callendar.
IList<WebElement> listOfElements = new IList<WebElement>();
listOfElements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='rc-row rc-widget-header']/table/thread/tr/th"));
//Search for the one that matches the element that you are looking for.
foreach(IWebElement element in listOfElements){
      if(element.Text.equals("Sun 1/22"){
         element.Click();
      }
}
```

Comment: There are rows which display time slots as 09:00:00 or 09:15:00 in 24 hour format. So, if want to click on Sun 1/22 at 9 AM. Then how I can achieve it.

Comment: You would probably need to change that "Sun 1/22" to the value that you want to click on, like "Sun 1/22 09:00:00 if I understood correctly. Is this timestamp that you are referring to the same that is present on the screenshot?

Comment: if you see html code there two different block of code one for header which displays date and other which display time in row. There is no association between date and time i guess in this table. Please suggest